# Create wrapper around object holding objects with functions

Tags: typescript

```
class APIContainer {
    api1!: API1;
    api2!: API2;
}

class API1 {
    postA(x: string): string { return '' }
    postB(x: number): number { return 1 }
    patchA(x: string): string { return '' }
}

class API2 {
    postX(x: string): string { return '' }
    postY(x: number): number { return 1 }
    patchX(x: string): string { return '' }
}

type ExtractPostMethods<T> = T extends `post${infer V}` ? V : never;

// this doesn't work, I get an error on the third parameter and the return value
function doCall<T extends keyof APIContainer, U extends ExtractPostMethods<keyof APIContainer[T]>>(api: T, entity: U, data: Parameters<APIContainer[T][`post${U}`]>[0]): ReturnType<APIContainer[T][`post${U}`]> {
    const container = new APIContainer;
    return container[api][`post${entity}`](data); // this doesn't work either
}

const result = doCall('api1', 'A', '1'); // this works, correctly expects string as 3rd param
result.length; // this works, correctly returns type string
```

See [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=5&pln=22&pc=11#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) for the actual errors

There's an object apiContainer which contains instances of actual API adapters. I'm trying to create a method which as first argument takes a key of apiContainer, the second parameter can be any method of that adapter, as long as it starts with `post`, but without the actual `post` part, and the third argument should basically be the same as the first argument of the referenced method. As you can see, I'm getting some errors in the playground, and I'm stuck on how to resolve these (if even possible).

Interestingly, it works, even though the function itself throws some errors.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!

I modified your some arguments and endpoints here and there to better show off the results, but the core logic remains unchanged.

`doCall` got a bunch of generics, so its easier to decipher what's going on:

- `ApiName` is any of the API's name in `APIContainer`.
- `Api` is an API instance.
- `TrimmedApiPostMethodName` is a union of all post method names in `Api`, trimmed (without `post` part).
- `FullApiPostMethodName` is a union of `TrimmedApiPostMethodName` keys, but with `post`.
- `ApiPostMethodUntyped` is a method referenced by `postMethodNameTrimmed`. Its not yet typed to be a function, just for clarity.
- `ApiPostMethod` is a method referenced by `postMethodNameTrimmed` typed as a function.

Now, I wasn't able to property type the `apiPostMethodName` variable due to complexity caused by trimming and whatnot of the property names, so it remains a `string` with `any` assertion on `postMethod`, sorry :(

As a bonus, `postMethodArgs` argument is defined with a spread syntax, which allows to pass as many post method arguments as defined there.

```
class APIContainer {
  api1: API1;
  api2: API2;
}

class API1 {
  postA(x: string, y: number): string { return '' }
  postB(x: number): number { return 1 }
  patchA(x: string): string { return '' }
}

class API2 {
  postX(x: string): string { return '' }
  postY(x: number): number { return 1 }
  patchD(x: string): string { return '' }
}

type TrimPostPrefix<T> = T extends `post${infer V}` ? V : never;

function doCall<
  ApiName extends keyof APIContainer,
  Api extends APIContainer[ApiName],
  TrimmedApiPostMethodName extends TrimPostPrefix<keyof Api>,
  FullApiPostMethodName extends `post${TrimmedApiPostMethodName}`,
  ApiPostMethodUntyped extends (FullApiPostMethodName extends keyof Api ? Api[FullApiPostMethodName] : never),
  ApiPostMethod extends (ApiPostMethodUntyped extends (...args: any[]) => any ? ApiPostMethodUntyped : never)
>(
  apiName: ApiName,
  postMethodNameTrimmed: TrimmedApiPostMethodName,
  ...postMethodArgs: Parameters<ApiPostMethod>
): ReturnType<ApiPostMethod> {
  const container = new APIContainer;
  const api = container[apiName];
  const apiPostMethodName = `post${postMethodNameTrimmed}`;
  const postMethod: ApiPostMethod = (api as any)[apiPostMethodName];
  
  return postMethod(postMethodArgs);
}

const r1 = doCall('api1', 'A', '1', 123);
// OK - 2 args for that method, type is correct

const r2 = doCall('api1', 'B', '1', 123);
// ERROR - as expected, for this method 2nd arg is not allowed

const r3 = doCall('api1', 'foo');
// ERROR - as expected, foo is not allowed

const r4 = doCall('api2', 'X', 'str');
// OK - second api working too

const r5 = doCall('api2', 'D');
// ERROR - as expected, cannot call patch for second api, only post is allowed
```